# Twitter for beginner

Tags: twitter

I want to make a small application (desktop/laptop for beginners) such that I can login to my twitter account and the application can tweet for me, lets say i can pass the tweet as an argument for the app.

So let us say that if I make the app in Java, basically it can be a function like:

```
LoginToTwitter(username, password) {
    someLoginApi();     // is there any apis exposed by twitter
}

Tweet(String Tweet) {

someApiTweet();

}
```

I did some research on this. Found a framework fabric. But it seems it is a plugin to tweet from a website. But I want to make a simple app to do it from my laptop for example. 
I also went through a lot of previous question asked on this. But I could not really find this. 
If anyone can guide me to the question which talks about this or any resource that I can look upon to solve this problem, it will be great help!

Thanks a ton
Regards
Ankur

Comment: Pick a language, get an API Implementation: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex for the link.

Comment: Hello Alex, after creating my first simple program, I now want to make a small program so that others can tweet from the same code. How do I do this? Can you help? There is a similar question but hasnt been answered. stackoverflow.com/q/27160022/4353383 Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the full working code that sends tweets to Twitter using Php. Hope it helps!

[LINK](http://sourceexplorer.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-post-tweet-to-twitter-using-php.html)

Comment: Hello Yuva thanks a lot for the video. It was a great start for beginers. I was able to tweet from my application.

Comment: You're welcome. You can upvote and accept the answer. It will be useful for upcoming users! :)

Comment: Hello Yuva, after creating my first simple program, I now want to make a small program so that others can tweet from the same code. How do I do this? Can you help? There is a similar question but hasnt been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27160022/4353383 Thanks a lot